# Swift: Result values in '? :' expression have mismatching types 'Class' and '()'

Tags: swift

I'm getting this error:

`Result values in '? :' expression have mismatching types 'MySection' and '()'` where MySection is a class

In this lines of code:

```
let myVariable = mySection.rawValue == 0 ?
            myClass.doSomethingAtIndex:(index: indexPath.row) :
            myClass.doSomethingElseAtIndex(index: indexPath.row)
```

Any of you knows why I'm getting this error or how can I fix this error or work around this?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: Do you have an extra `:` inside `myClass.doSomethingAtIndex:(index: indexPath.row)`?

Comment: You need to look at the return types of your myClass.doSomethingAtIndex and myClass.doSomethingElseAtIndex functions. It looks like they return values of different types, which won't work.

Comment: I think dashblinkenlight spotted it. You have a colon that doesn't belong.

Comment: Yep that extra ':' character  changes the whole statement.  Now the `myClass.doSomethingAtIndex` is what it would try for when correct and `(index: indexPath.row)` when incorrect.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth I'm trying to do a boolean comparison and take one or the other  that is the reason of the ":"

Comment: I will post it as an answer to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this:

```
let myVariable = mySection.rawValue == 0 ?
            myClass.doSomethingAtIndex:(index: indexPath.row) :
            myClass.doSomethingElseAtIndex(index: indexPath.row)
```

and it should be this:

```
let myVariable = mySection.rawValue == 0 ?
            myClass.doSomethingAtIndex(index: indexPath.row) :
            myClass.doSomethingElseAtIndex(index: indexPath.row)
```

Note the ':' that I have removed from between the doSomethingAtIndex and the bracket '('